# In which file can we modify what is logged / non logged by apache?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, logs, apache-virtualhost

I have a Debian 8 with Apache. My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is like the follwing.
How, and in which config file, can I ask Apache **to not log in `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` the traffic coming from http://www.mysite2.org or from http://www.mysite3.org/subdir/ ?** All the rest should be logged to the same file `other_vhosts_access.log` as usual.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite1.org
  DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite1
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite2.org
  DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite2
  <Directory />
  ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite3.org
  DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite3
  <Directory />
  ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

+ 10 other virtual hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

each virtual host needs a deffinition of errorlog and common log, without these the default log is used, also note, it's worth creating a default vhost which catches all traffic that is not for one of your domains (people who point their dns at your website). This can have bad serp consequences as it's dupe content.

so, in each vhost;

```
    ErrorLog "logs/web1-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/web1-access_log" common

    ErrorLog "logs/web2-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/web2-access_log" common
```

UPDATE:

didn't see the part on not logging a particular dir, this would be achived by setting an enviroment var.

Comment: Does `CustomLog "logs/web2-access_log" common` need to be in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file, inside `<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>`?

Comment: Something else, as asked in question, how to not log trafic from a subdir of a virtual host? i.e. http://www.mysite3.org/ traffic should be logged, but http://www.mysite3.org/subdir/ not logged ?

Comment: customlog should be defined in every vhost, every vhost should have it's own log file as best practice.

Comment: in which configuration file should we set custom log?

Comment: inside the virtualhost

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeJonesey for his answer. To add more details, here is the solution, to put in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite3.org
  DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite3
  <Directory />
  ...
  </Directory>
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/subdir(.*)$" dontlog
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined env=!dontlog
</VirtualHost>
```